# Selenium setup/teardown best practices- returning data to orginal state

Tags: selenium

```
    {
        Assert.That(_editUserPage.State.SelectedText, Is.EqualTo("Illinois"));
        _editUserPage.State.SelectedText = "New York";
        Assert.That(_editUserPage.State.SelectedText, Is.EqualTo("New York"));
        _editUserPage.SaveChanges();
        Assert.That(_editUserPage.State.SelectedText, Is.EqualTo("New York"));
     }
```

In my example above, I am changing the User's state from Illinois to New York; my question is: should I change the state back to the orignal value of Illiois at the end of the test?

I have roughly 20 other independent tests in the same file and I wanted to know what the best practice is for returning data to the original state.  We are using setup/teardown for the entire test suite, just not within each individual test.

Answer (score 1):

Best practice so far which I did see was this:

1. The test had one test data input (excel sheet)
2. Each run would add some prefix to the data (e.g. name Pavel => Test01_Pavel)
3. Test did verify that such data do not exist in the system
4. Test created testing data according to the input and verified that those data are present
5. Test deleted all testing data and verified that those data are deleted.

But the really best answer is "it depends." I, personally, am not deleting any test data from the system because

- Test environment is strictly divided from prod one
- Test data can be useful later on during performance testing (e.g. downloading list of users from the system)

So the real question which you should ask yourself is:

- Does deleting test data at the end bring anything good to you?
- And vice versa: What happens if the test data remain in the system?

BTW, if you feel like that "the application will definitely break if there is too much nonsense/dummy data in it" you should definitely test that scenario. Imagine that your service will become popular over night (Charlie sheen tweeting about using your page:) ) and millions of users would like to register themselves.

Answer (score 0):

The approach taken in the company I work for is:

1. Spin up a dedicated test environment in cloud (AWS)
2. Kick off suite of tests
3. Each test would insert the data it requires
4. Once the test suite has completed then tear down the servers, inc. db

This way you have a fresh database each time the tests run and therefore the only danger of bad data breaking a test is if 2 tests in the suite are generating conflicting data.